# Как загружать и сохранять файлы в WebKitView iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

Как можно сделать загрузку файлов (и сохранение их в памяти приложения) в WebKit на iOS на языке Swift? Например я нажимаю на ссылку, которая выдаёт какой-то файл и начинается скачивание. Но если просто добавить WebKitView на экран приложения, открыть в нём какой-нибудь сайт, то при нажатии в нём на ссылки на скачивание ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    ....
}
```

Далее получаете ссылку, на которую нажимает пользователь, проверяете что это файл (например, если она заканчивается на .zip) и скачиваете через обычные методы (я советую использовать [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading-data-to-a-file))

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        print(navigationAction.request.url ?? "")
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString{

        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вариант. Но возможны случаи, когда в конце адреса не указывается имя файла с его расширением. Например можно скачать zip файл по ссылке http://site.ru/file.zip , а можно http://site.ru/load. В таком случае написанным методом обработать не получится. Понять точно, что по этой ссылке происходит скачивание файла - можно с помощью аналогичного метода в WKNavigationDelegate, только не для navigationAction, а для navigationResponse. Там можно с помощью приходящих заголовков и mimeType определить, что в ответе пришел файл и затем скачать через Alamofire.

Comment: НО как я понимаю, я буду скачивать этот файл 2 раза - в WebView и потом с помощью Alamofire. Может можно как-нибудь получить содержимое ответа из WKWebView, чтобы не скачивать повторно?